# Should you mock modules within a beforeEach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

For example should you do something like:

(1)

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom')),
    useLocation: () => ({
      pathName: '/',
      search: '?something=everything'
    })
  }));
})
```

or is importing react-router-dom like that for every test wasteful (it seems so... if you have hundreds of tests this must cause test slowdown right)?

For example instead you could do this:

(2)

```
let mockUseLocation;
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom')),
  useLocation: () => mockUseLocation
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  mockUseLocation = {
    pathName: '/',
    search: '?something=everything'
  }
})
```

Is there a best practice about something like this? Is my intuition correct that the second option is better than the first?

Comment: You shouldn't mock modules within `beforeEach` because it _won't work correctly_ - unless the call to `jest.mock` is at the top level of the module, it won't get hoisted before the other imports and the code you're testing will be using the real implementation.

Comment: ahhh wow thanks for pointing that out!! So (2) is the correct way to do things!